# Optimizing sum, ZipList, Vector, and unboxed types

Tags: haskell, optimization, lazy-evaluation

I have identified the following hotspot function that is currently 25% of my program execution time:

```
type EncodeLookup = [(GF256Elm, [GF256Elm])]

-- | Given the coefficients of a Polynomial and an x value,
-- calculate its corresponding y value.
-- coefficients are in ascending order [d, a1, a2, a3...] where y = d + a1*x + a2*x^2 ...
calc :: EncodeLookup -> [GF256Elm] -> [GF256Elm]
calc xsLookup poly =
    map f xsLookup
        where
            f (_, pList) = 
                let zl = (*) <$> ZipList (pList)  <*> ZipList poly
                    lst = getZipList zl
                    s = sum lst 
                in s
```

Where `GF256Elm` is just a `newtype` wrapper around an `Int`, with custom `*` and other operations defined for it (FiniteFields).

Here are the related profiling data for this function:

```
                                    individual     inherited
COST CENTRE       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
calc              544      794418    1.6    3.1    27.5   19.7
 calc.f           698     3972090    0.9    0.0    25.9   16.6
  calc.f.s        709     3972090    7.4    6.2    11.0    7.8
   fromInteger    711     3972090    0.7    0.0     0.7    0.0
   +              710    11916270    2.9    1.6     2.9    1.6
  calc.f.lst      708     3972090    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  calc.f.zl       699     3972090    6.8    8.8    14.0    8.8
   *              712    11916270    7.2    0.0     7.2    0.0
```

My observations:

1. `sum`'s slowness probably came from the lazy list thunks
2. `*` calculation takes a while too. You can see the full implementation of `GF256Elm` [here](https://github.com/jtcwang/HaskSplit/blob/master/src/lib/FiniteField/GF256.hs). `*` is basically a vector lookup of pregenerated table and some bit flipping.
3. 'ZipList` seems to take a significant amount of time as well.

My questions:

1. How would I go about optimizing this function? Especially regarding `sum` - would using `deepSeq` on the list make it faster?
2. Should I be using unboxed `Int#` type for `GF256Elm`? What other ways can I improve the speed of `GF256Elm`'s operations?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing the `sum` to `foldl' (+) 0`

Comment: Why are you using ZipList? it's typeclass machinery is super overkill. try `zl = zipWith (*) pList poly` to get rid of your third biggest cost center. bonus: sticking this up against sum *should* fuse.

Comment: @Thomas it looks like you can turn that comment into an answer since it resolved the question?

Comment: @jatcwang did that actually solve the problem?

Comment: @Thomas It's been a while, but yes I believe it did.